Find the statement currently running in my PL/pgSQL code block
Is there a way to figure out which statement from the block is currently running in Postgres? (Even extra extensions or tracing might be an option)
Below is the quick way to reproduce but in real scenario the block is way more complicated.
do
$$ 
declare
  x int;
  c char;
  d int := 3;
begin
  select pg_sleep(d), 11112 into c, x;
   
  select pg_sleep(d), 11113 into c, x;

  select pg_sleep(d), 11114 into c, x;
end
$$;

pg_stat_statements / pg_stat_activity show only the main block, not specific queries.

In fact, pg_stat_statements does have info about statements inside the block (when pg_stat_statements.track = all). However, they are normalized so we cannot see actual values. Anyway, we can monitor what is going on by checking calls.
postgres=# select queryid, query, calls from pg_stat_statements where query ~ 'pg_sleep' and not query ~ 'do';
       queryid        |         query          | calls 
----------------------+------------------------+-------
 -2604025637555979379 | select pg_sleep(d), $5 |    43
(1 row)

The ideal solution though is to use pgsentinel.
It shows what is running at the moment as well associated top level block.
postgres=# select ash_time, query, queryid --, top_level_query
postgres-# from pg_active_session_history
postgres-# where ash_time > timestamp '2024-10-26 13:40:00';
           ash_time            |           query           |       queryid        
-------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------
 2024-10-26 13:41:00.726212+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11112 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:01.730933+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11112 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:02.733903+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11112 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:03.737171+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11113 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:04.74009+01  | select pg_sleep(d), 11113 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:05.742954+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11113 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:06.748392+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11114 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:07.75082+01  | select pg_sleep(d), 11114 | -2604025637555979379
 2024-10-26 13:41:08.754098+01 | select pg_sleep(d), 11114 | -2604025637555979379
(9 rows)


The simple solution is to throw in, at positions you want to know ...
RAISE NOTICE 'Starting query 2 ...';

Obviously only visible for the same session.
auto_explain
You can achieve that for all statements without altering the code block using auto_explain. It's a bit heavy-handed because it also reports the query plan for each. (Very short for the given example, but may get quite verbose for complex queries.) But I am not aware of a simpler way. See:

Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function

Demo:
test=> SET ROLE postgres;
SET
test=# LOAD 'auto_explain';
LOAD
test=# SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON; -- statements inside code blocks
SET
test=# SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1;       -- exclude queries taking < 1 ms
SET
test=# SET client_min_messages TO log;              -- get log msg in client
SET
test=# do
test-# $$ 
test$# declare
test$#   x int;
test$#   c char;
test$#   d int := 2;
test$# begin
test$#   select pg_sleep(d), 1 into c, x;
test$# 
test$#   select pg_sleep(d), 2 into c, x;
test$# 
test$#   select pg_sleep(d), 3 into c, x;
test$# end
test$# $$;
LOG:  statement: do
$$ 
declare
  x int;
  c char;
  d int := 2;
begin
  select pg_sleep(d), 1 into c, x;

  select pg_sleep(d), 2 into c, x;

  select pg_sleep(d), 3 into c, x;
end
$$;
LOG:  duration: 2002.483 ms  plan:
Query Text: select pg_sleep(d), 1
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
LOG:  duration: 2002.134 ms  plan:
Query Text: select pg_sleep(d), 2
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
LOG:  duration: 2002.423 ms  plan:
Query Text: select pg_sleep(d), 3
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=8)
LOG:  duration: 6009.303 ms
DO
test=#


Thanks for this. This is really good option when we can do a bit of preparation before running the statemement and when pgsentinel is not available.

One feature of plpgsql_check is the tracing.
postgres=# do $$ begin perform fx(10,null, 'now', e'stěhule'); end; $$;
NOTICE:  #0            ->> start of block inline_code_block (oid=0)
NOTICE:  #0.1       1  --> start of PERFORM
NOTICE:  #2              ->> start of function fx(integer,integer,date,text) (oid=16405)
NOTICE:  #2                   call by inline_code_block line 1 at PERFORM
NOTICE:  #2                  "a" => '10', "b" => null, "c" => '2020-08-04', "d" => 'stěhule'
NOTICE:  #2.1       1    --> start of PERFORM
NOTICE:  #2.1                "a" => '10'
NOTICE:  #4                ->> start of function fx(integer) (oid=16404)
NOTICE:  #4                     call by fx(integer,integer,date,text) line 1 at PERFORM
NOTICE:  #4                    "a" => '10'
NOTICE:  #4.1       6      --> start of assignment
NOTICE:  #4.1                  "a" => '10', "b" => '20'
NOTICE:  #4.1              <-- end of assignment (elapsed time=0.076 ms)
NOTICE:  #4.1                  "res" => '130'
NOTICE:  #4.2       7      --> start of RETURN
NOTICE:  #4.2                  "res" => '130'
NOTICE:  #4.2              <-- end of RETURN (elapsed time=0.054 ms)
NOTICE:  #4                <<- end of function fx (elapsed time=0.373 ms)
NOTICE:  #2.1            <-- end of PERFORM (elapsed time=0.589 ms)
NOTICE:  #2              <<- end of function fx (elapsed time=0.727 ms)
NOTICE:  #0.1          <-- end of PERFORM (elapsed time=1.147 ms)
NOTICE:  #0            <<- end of block (elapsed time=1.286 ms)


It would have been much more useful if you posted specific set commands as well exact output for the original question rather than just providing link to your repo.

@SlimboyFat - first you need to install the extension plpgsql_check. Second, you should to allow tracing - from security reason, it is not enabled by default. Last, just by SELECT plpgsql_check_tracer(true) the tracer will be active. The link is there because plpgsql_check is not part of Postgres.

Technically, you can just flip debug_print_plan on and it'll do exactly that:
set debug_print_plan to on;

Problem is, that'll keep throwing whole parse trees at you. While those do hold everything about the currently processed statement, I wouldn't expect anyone to prefer or even tolerate that format if all you wanted was to see a checkpoint, the line it's on:
do $$
declare x int;
        c char;
        d int := 1; i int;
begin select pg_sleep(d), 11112 into c, x;
      for i in 1..5 loop
        select pg_sleep(d); select i;  
      end loop;
      select pg_sleep(d), 11114 into c, x;
end $$;

You can see pg_sleep() only as its oid under :funcid 2626 a few miles into this (this isn't all it spewed out):
LOG:  plan:
DETAIL:     {PLANNEDSTMT
   :commandType 1
   :queryId 0
   :hasReturning false
   :hasModifyingCTE false
   :canSetTag true
   :transientPlan false
   :dependsOnRole false
   :parallelModeNeeded false
   :jitFlags 0
   :planTree
      {RESULT
      :startup_cost 0.00
      :total_cost 0.01
      :plan_rows 1
      :plan_width 4
      :parallel_aware false
      :parallel_safe false
      :async_capable false
      :plan_node_id 0
      :targetlist (
         {TARGETENTRY
         :expr
            {CONST
            :consttype 23
            :consttypmod -1
            :constcollid 0
            :constlen 4
            :constbyval true
            :constisnull false
            :location 0
            :constvalue 4 [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
            }
         :resno 1
         :resname ?column?
         :ressortgroupref 0
         :resorigtbl 0
         :resorigcol 0
         :resjunk false
         }
      )
      :qual <>
      :lefttree <>
      :righttree <>
      :initPlan <>
      :extParam (b)
      :allParam (b)
      :resconstantqual <>
      }
   :rtable (
      {RANGETBLENTRY
      :alias <>
      :eref
         {ALIAS
         :aliasname *RESULT*
         :colnames <>
         }
      :rtekind 8
      :lateral false
      :inh false
      :inFromCl false
      :requiredPerms 0
      :checkAsUser 0
      :selectedCols (b)
      :insertedCols (b)
      :updatedCols (b)
      :extraUpdatedCols (b)
      :securityQuals <>
      }
   )
   :resultRelations <>
   :appendRelations <>
   :subplans <>
   :rewindPlanIDs (b)
   :rowMarks <>
   :relationOids <>
   :invalItems <>
   :paramExecTypes <>
   :utilityStmt <>
   :stmt_location 0
   :stmt_len 0
   }

LOG:  plan:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              [384/1854]
DETAIL:     {PLANNEDSTMT
   :commandType 1
   :queryId 0
   :hasReturning false
   :hasModifyingCTE false
   :canSetTag true
   :transientPlan false
   :dependsOnRole false
   :parallelModeNeeded false
   :jitFlags 0
   :planTree
      {RESULT
      :startup_cost 0.00
      :total_cost 0.01
      :plan_rows 1
      :plan_width 8
      :parallel_aware false
      :parallel_safe false
      :async_capable false
      :plan_node_id 0
      :targetlist (
         {TARGETENTRY
         :expr
            {FUNCEXPR
            :funcid 2626
            :funcresulttype 2278
            :funcretset false
            :funcvariadic false
            :funcformat 0
            :funccollid 0
            :inputcollid 0
            :args (
               {CONST
               :consttype 701
               :consttypmod -1
               :constcollid 0
               :constlen 8
               :constbyval true
               :constisnull false
               :location -1
               :constvalue 8 [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 -16 63 ]
               }
            )
            :location 7
            }
         :resno 1
         :resname pg_sleep
         :ressortgroupref 0
         :resorigtbl 0
         :resorigcol 0
         :resjunk false
         }
         {TARGETENTRY
         :expr
            {CONST
            :consttype 23
            :consttypmod -1
            :constcollid 0
            :constlen 4
            :constbyval true
            :constisnull false
            :location 20
            :constvalue 4 [ 104 43 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
            }
         :resno 2
         :resname ?column?
         :ressortgroupref 0
         :resorigtbl 0
         :resorigcol 0
         :resjunk false
         }
      )
      :qual <>
      :lefttree <>
      :righttree <>
      :initPlan <>
      :extParam (b)
      :allParam (b)
      :resconstantqual <>
      }
   :rtable (
      {RANGETBLENTRY
      :alias <>
      :eref
         {ALIAS
         :aliasname *RESULT*
         :colnames <>
         }
      :rtekind 8
      :lateral false
      :inh false
      :inFromCl false
      :requiredPerms 0
      :checkAsUser 0
      :selectedCols (b)
      :insertedCols (b)
      :updatedCols (b)
      :extraUpdatedCols (b)
      :securityQuals <>
      }
   )
   :resultRelations <>
   :appendRelations <>
   :subplans <>
   :rewindPlanIDs (b)
   :rowMarks <>
   :relationOids <>
   :invalItems <>
   :paramExecTypes <>
   :utilityStmt <>
   :stmt_location 0
   :stmt_len 0
   }


As already suggested by @Erwin Brandstetter, it's best to equip your code with RAISE at adequate message levels.
